# Report Generation in Node.js Using Node-Jasper Package

Tags: node.js, express, npm, jasper-reports, node-modules

I am trying to generate a report using node-jasper package in node.js.
When i write the code without class implementation then the code works fine following is the workable code.

```
jasper = require('node-jasper')({
        path: '../lib/jasperreports-5.6.0',
        reports: {
            hw: {
                jasper: '../jasperFiles/NodeIreportTest.jasper'
            }
        },
        drivers: {
            mysql: {
                path: '../lib/com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar',
                class: 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', //odbc driver//sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver //mysqlDriver// com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
                type: 'mysql'
            }
        },
        conns: {
            dbserver1: {
                host: '192.168.1.164',
                port: 3306,
                dbname: 'dbname',
                user: 'user',
                pass: '1234',
                driver: 'mysql'
            }
        },
        defaultConn: 'dbserver1'
    });
```

Following is complete object found when i debug the code. which is having (hm) property.

[image: Following is complete object found when i debug the code.]

but when i tried to introduce the classes and make the code standard i get and error `TypeError: self.hm is not a constructor`
following is class implementation of the same code

```
class ReportModel {
    constructor(strJasperPath, objDataObject, intClientIP) {
        this.strJasperPath = strJasperPath;
        this.objDataObject = objDataObject;
        this.intClientIP = intClientIP;
    }

    makeReport() {

        return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
            jasper = require('node-jasper')({
                path: '../lib/jasperreports-5.6.0',
                reports: {
                    hw: {
                        //jasper: '../jasperFiles/NodeIreportTest.jasper'
                        jasper: '../jasperFiles/' + this.strJasperPath + '.jasper' //path to report
                    }
                },
                drivers: {
                    mysql: {
                        path: '../lib/com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar',
                        class: 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', //odbc driver//sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver //mysqlDriver// com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
                        type: 'mysql'
                    }
                },
                conns: {
                    dbserver1: {
                        host: '192.168.1.164',
                        port: 3306,
                        dbname: 'dbname',
                        user: 'user',
                        pass: '1234',
                        driver: 'mysql'
                    }
                },
                defaultConn: 'dbserver1'
            });



            var report = {
                report: 'hw',
                data: this.objDataObject
            }
            var pdf = jasper.pdf(report);


            var strReportName = this.strJasperPath + intClientIP + '.pdf'
            var filepath = "./reports/" + strReportName

            var filename = {
                "filepath": serverConfig.reporthost + path.basename(filepath)
            };

            //check if file is present or not 
            fs.access(filepath, fs.constants.F_OK | fs.constants.W_OK, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    //file is not present 
                    fs.writeFile("./reports/" + strReportName, new Buffer(pdf, 'binary'), (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        }
                        resolve(filename);
                    });
                } else {
                    //file is present then delete it and then create it 
                    fs.unlink(filepath, (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        } else {

                            fs.writeFile("./reports/" + strReportName, new Buffer(pdf, 'binary'), (err) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log('WriteFile', err)
                                }
                            resolve(filename);
                            });
                        }

                    });

                }
            });
        });


    }
}
```

following is the object which is not having hm property with class implementation.

[image: following is the object which is not having hm property]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1) Remove your Jasper declaration out of the class body and remove hw object from it like below code

```
jasper = require('node-jasper')({
    path: '../lib/jasperreports-5.6.0',
    reports: {
       // hw removed from this place
    },
    drivers: {
        mysql: {
            path: '../lib/com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar',
            class: 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', //odbc driver//sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver //mysqlDriver// com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            type: 'mysql'
        }
    },
    conns: {
        dbserver1: {
            host: '192.168.1.164',
            port: 3306,
            dbname: 'node_incrency_minpcs',
            user: 'RAHUL',
            pass: '1234',
            driver: 'mysql'
        }
    },
    defaultConn: 'dbserver1'
});
```

Step 2) Add declaration of hw object in constructor like below

```
constructor(strReportName) {
        jasper.reports = {
            hw: {
                jasper: '../jasperFiles/' + strReportName+ '.jasper' 
            }
        }
    }
```

Step 3) add other parameters to function body that is `makeReport` function as `makeReport(strJasperPath, objDataObject, intClientIP)`

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the jasper instance has not yet been created.
The creators of lib did not make any flags to warn the correct time to call ".pdf"
Leave it at that and,

Try it:

```
    setTimeout(() {
     var report = {
                report: 'hw',
                data: this.objDataObject
            }
            var pdf = jasper.pdf(report);


            var strReportName = this.strJasperPath + intClientIP + '.pdf'
            var filepath = "./reports/" + strReportName

            var filename = {
                "filepath": serverConfig.reporthost + path.basename(filepath)
            };

            //check if file is present or not 
            fs.access(filepath, fs.constants.F_OK | fs.constants.W_OK, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    //file is not present 
                    fs.writeFile("./reports/" + strReportName, new Buffer(pdf, 'binary'), (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        }
                        resolve(filename);
                    });
                } else {
                    //file is present then delete it and then create it 
                    fs.unlink(filepath, (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        } else {

                            fs.writeFile("./reports/" + strReportName, new Buffer(pdf, 'binary'), (err) => {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log('WriteFile', err)
                                }
                            resolve(filename);
                            });
                        }

                    });

                }
            });
        });
}, 5000)
```